# latex - getting specific problem number

Tags: latex, miktex

i wanted to do the following...   Problem 3.

in latex i use the following

```
          \newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
          \begin{prob} 
          ...
          \end{prob}
```

it starts as follows Problem 1., is it possible to to Problem 3. instead,... can you show me how? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\setcounter` macro:

> `\setcounter{`*counter*`}{`*value*`}`

Be careful that the *value* is zero-based, so Problem 1 corresponds to a counter value of 0.

For example, to start with Problem 3:

```
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\setcounter{prob}{2}
\begin{prob}
  ... 
\end{prob}
```